# Getting the timezone (GMT) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I have an app that displays the timezones of different countries. Currently the code looks like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 7{
    cell.aseanDate.text = dayFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date)
    cell.aseanTime.text = dateFormatter2.string(from: Date() as Date)
    cell.aseanTime.textAlignment = .center
    cell.aseanTimeZone.text = "\(TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+07")!)"
}
```

The time itself is displayed properly but under`aseanTimezone.text` it displays GMT +0800(fixed)

Is it possible to change it so it displays the GMT but without the first zero and the word (fixed)?

Comment: If you are hardcoding the timezone then why bother creating the `TimeZone` instance at all? Just put the specific string you want.

Comment: Unrelated but `Date() as Date` is pointless. Just use `Date()`. No need to cast a `Date` to a `Date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this method

`localizedName(for style: NSTimeZone.NameStyle, locale: Locale?)`

But, it will remove the trailing zeros too `GMT+7`

```
TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+07")!.localizedName(for: .shortStandard, locale: nil)! // => GMT+7
```

Other available options

```
.standard
.shortStandard
.daylightSaving
.shortDaylightSaving
.generic
.shortGeneric
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 7 {
    let newDate = Date()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"Your timezoon string here!!")
    cell.aseanTimeZone.text = = formatter.string(from: newDate)
}
```